# Laravel trying to save HTML in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel app which manages articles. These articles have a content section, which is being stored within the database as string (varchar). It worked properly when I did not put in some big content, but now it says:

> String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'content' at row 1

How am I supposed to store the content in the database as HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel supports the `text`, `mediumText` and `longText` column types which resolve to the respective MySQL equivalent.

An appropriate migration entry for your instance would be:

```
$table->text('content');
```

Comment: Perfect. I tottaly forgot about them although I used it in my older projects. Thanks

Comment: By the way, do not forget that `text()` field cannot be NULL, so `nullable()` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand the size of the `content` column in the database. This means change the type from `varchar` to `text`.